Пытаюсь привязать к аватару VRC предмет и ошибка AV3MANAGER
пытаюсь соединить анимации и тут ошибка юнити, переустановка av3 не помогла
VRLabs.AV3Manager.AV3ManagerFunctions.AnalyzeWdStateMachine (UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorStateMachine stateMachine, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] states, System.String layerName) (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/AV3ManagerFunctions.cs:725)
VRLabs.AV3Manager.AV3ManagerFunctions.AnalyzeWDState (VRC.SDK3.Avatars.Components.VRCAvatarDescriptor descriptor) (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/AV3ManagerFunctions.cs:488)
VRLabs.AV3Manager.WDTab.UpdateWDList () (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/Tabs/WDTab.cs:112)
VRLabs.AV3Manager.WDTab.UpdateTab (VRC.SDK3.Avatars.Components.VRCAvatarDescriptor avatar) (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/Tabs/WDTab.cs:105)
VRLabs.AV3Manager.AV3Manager.UpdateTabs () (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/AV3Manager.cs:123)
VRLabs.AV3Manager.AV3Manager.<LoadTopArea>b__8_0 (UnityEngine.UIElements.ChangeEvent`1[T] e) (at ./Packages/dev.vrlabs.av3manager/Editor/AV3Manager.cs:143)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventCallbackFunctor`1[TEventType].Invoke (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.PropagationPhase propagationPhase) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventCallbackRegistry.InvokeCallbacks (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.PropagationPhase propagationPhase) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler.UnityEngine.UIElements.IEventHandler.HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities.HandleEventAcrossPropagationPath (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatchUtilities.PropagateEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.DefaultDispatchingStrategy.DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, System.Boolean imguiEventIsInitiallyUsed) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEventQueue () (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.OpenGate () (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate.Dispose () (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher.Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase evt, UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel panel, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel.SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase e, UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode dispatchMode) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel panel) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& eventHandled) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration+<>c.<.cctor>b__1_2 (System.Int32 i, System.IntPtr ptr) (at <332857d8803a4878904bcf8f9581ec33>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility.ProcessEvent (System.Int32 instanceID, System.IntPtr nativeEventPtr, System.Boolean& result) (at <74d6aaa3aedf4a279751914e170fef65>:0)``` 

